# Create deep links in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink

I do not know how it called correctly, so I called it deep links. We know that if we have controller service and want to make link "/service/new" we must write new method on that controller, but what about deeper links like "service/new/create" for example?
P.S. without matching it in routes.rb, of course, for example `match  'service/new/create', to: 'service/new#create',   via: 'get'`

Comment: what this action `service/new/create` will do...? Tell us what is your intention...?

Comment: You can create your routes just like you need, there's no any restrictions.

Comment: _without matching it in routes.rb_ -- what ? :/

Comment: @MarekLipka, yes but what I must write in controller?

Comment: @old_school after your editions, I understand nothing from your question. So I don't really know how to answer it correctly.

Comment: Is it really called deep links?

Comment: @Vipala no, I just write it because of my poor English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OfCourse, you must write a controller action to handler a endpoint. For this purpose only there is a concept called  'Nested Resources'

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources